# Analytics Console on MFP 8.0 in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I have created an MFP8 instance on Bluemix and when I login to my console, I do not see the "Analytics Console" option in the top right of the page.  When I login to my local installation of MFP8 on a Windows machine, I can see that.  Is this something to do with the plan I have subscribed? I am using "Developer Plan".

Comment: in your service instance, have you "added analytics"? It's in the overview section

Answer (score 2):

You need to go into your MFP Bluemix instance and "Add Analytics".

[image]